# Converting PL/SQL code to SQLite

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sqlite

I would like to know how can I convert the following block of Oracle PL/SQL code into SQLite so that it can be used in an Objective C program:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL
INTO V_CUSTOMER_ID
FROM DUAL;
```

where `V_CUSTOMER_ID` is `CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE NOT NULL`, and
`CUSTOMER_ID` is integer type in table.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Do you want to know how to do this in the SQLite database?

Comment: Yes of course i want to know how to do this with sqlite database

Comment: I've reworded the question so that it's clear that it's about SQLite rather than Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have sequences.

To get an autoincrementing ID, you have to use an [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) column.

Answer (score 1):

CL is right. 
Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.

Long answer: If you declare a column of a table to be INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if the table is empty. (If the largest possible integer key, 9223372036854775807, then an unused key value is chosen at random.) For example, suppose you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
  a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  b INTEGER
);
```

With this table, the statement

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(NULL,123);
is logically equivalent to saying:

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES((SELECT max(a) FROM t1)+1,123);
```

There is a function named **sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()** which will return the integer key for the most recent insert operation.

Check the following for FAQ help on SQLite: http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q1